# RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout with android socket io

Tags: android, node.js, android-studio, socket.io

i am trying to make an android realtime chat using node js server and socket.io  this is the chatbox activity :

```
public class ChatBoxActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public RecyclerView myRecylerView ;
    public List<Message> MessageList ;
    public ChatBoxAdapter chatBoxAdapter;
    public EditText messagetxt ;
    public Button send ;
    //declare socket object
    private Socket socket;

    public String Nickname ;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat_box);

        messagetxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.message) ;
        send = (Button)findViewById(R.id.send);
        // get the nickame of the user
        Nickname= (String)getIntent().getExtras().getString(MainActivity.NICKNAME);
        //connect you socket client to the server
        try {
            socket = IO.socket("http://10.0.2.2:3000");
            socket.connect();
            socket.emit("join", Nickname);
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
       //setting up recyler
        MessageList = new ArrayList<>();
        myRecylerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.messagelist);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        myRecylerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        myRecylerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());



        // message send action
        send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //retrieve the nickname and the message content and fire the event messagedetection
                if(!messagetxt.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                    socket.emit("messagedetection",Nickname,"jfjdjfj");

                    messagetxt.setText(" ");
                }


            }
        });

        //implementing socket listeners
        socket.on("userjoinedthechat", new Emitter.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void call(final Object... args) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        String data = (String) args[0];

                        Toast.makeText(ChatBoxActivity.this,data, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });
            }
        });
        socket.on("userdisconnect", new Emitter.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void call(final Object... args) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        String data = (String) args[0];

                        Toast.makeText(ChatBoxActivity.this,data, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });
            }
        });
        socket.on("message", new Emitter.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void call(final Object... args) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        JSONObject data = (JSONObject) args[0];
                        try {
                            //extract data from fired event

                            String nickname = data.getString("senderNickname");
                            String message = data.getString("message");

                            // make instance of message

                            Message m = new Message(nickname,message);


                            //add the message to the messageList

                            MessageList.add(m);

                            // add the new updated list to the dapter
                            chatBoxAdapter = new ChatBoxAdapter(MessageList);

                            // notify the adapter to update the recycler view

                            chatBoxAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                            //set the adapter for the recycler view

                            myRecylerView.setAdapter(chatBoxAdapter);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }


                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        socket.disconnect();
  }
}
```

this is node js server code :

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send('<h1>Hello world</h1>');
});

io.on('connection',function(socket){
    console.log('one user connected '+socket.id);




    socket.on('CHAT' , function (data) {
        console.log('======CHAT message========== ');
        console.log(data);
        socket.emit('CHAT',data);

    });

    socket.on('disconnect',function(){
        console.log('one user disconnected '+socket.id);
    });

})

http.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log('server listening on port 3000');
})
```

details about the error : 
the server is running correctly it's printing 'server listening on port 3000' in the console .  also when i join the chat the socket 'join' and 'disconnect' are emmitted since i get this in my console log:

one user connected xVs1-xYtvNA5sd-dAAAA

one user disconnected xVs1-xYtvNA5sd-dAAAA

only the connect and disconnect socket events are emitted but the send and recevie messages aren't being emitted .

Comment: `myRecylerView.setAdapter(chatBoxAdapter)` should be called at the same place you set item animator and LayoutManager

Comment: You should set `ChatBoxAdapter` to the `RecyclerView` in `onCreate`, not in `socket.on("message"`

Comment: @EpicPandaForce more details about setting the recyclerview adapter error in the update version of the post please check it . thank you

Comment: Because you put it above the line `myRecylerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.messagelist);` and you should not have put it above that line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to give the recyclerView an adapter at the same time you give it the layoutManager... It is skipping the layout here when getting the adaper

[UPDATE]
For the socket not emmiting the message on your server you are not listening for the "message" or on the android side you are not listening for the "chat" I would modify your server side code to match your android application as such

Final code:

```
public class ChatBoxActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public RecyclerView myRecylerView ;
    public List<Message> MessageList ;
    public ChatBoxAdapter chatBoxAdapter;
    public EditText messagetxt ;
    public Button send ;
    //declare socket object
    private Socket socket;

    public String Nickname ;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat_box);

        messagetxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.message) ;
        send = (Button)findViewById(R.id.send);
        // get the nickame of the user
        Nickname= (String)getIntent().getExtras().getString(MainActivity.NICKNAME);
        //connect you socket client to the server
        try {
            socket = IO.socket("http://10.0.2.2:3000");
            socket.connect();
            socket.emit("join", Nickname);
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
       //setting up recyler
        MessageList = new ArrayList<>();
        myRecylerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.messagelist);




        // message send action
        send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //retrieve the nickname and the message content and fire the event messagedetection
                if(!messagetxt.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                    socket.emit("message",Nickname,"jfjdjfj");

                    messagetxt.setText(" ");
                }


            }
        });

        //implementing socket listeners
        socket.on("userjoinedthechat", new Emitter.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void call(final Object... args) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        String data = (String) args[0];

                        Toast.makeText(ChatBoxActivity.this,data, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });
            }
        });

        socket.on("userdisconnect", new Emitter.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void call(final Object... args) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        String data = (String) args[0];

                        Toast.makeText(ChatBoxActivity.this,data, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });
            }
        });

        socket.on("message", new Emitter.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void call(final Object... args) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        JSONObject data = (JSONObject) args[0];
                        try {
                            //extract data from fired event

                            String nickname = data.getString("senderNickname");
                            String message = data.getString("message");

                            // make instance of message

                            Message m = new Message(nickname,message);


                            //add the message to the messageList

                            MessageList.add(m);

                            // add the new updated list to the dapter
                            chatBoxAdapter = new ChatBoxAdapter(MessageList);

                            // notify the adapter to update the recycler view

                            chatBoxAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                            //set the adapter for the recycler view
                            RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
                            myRecylerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
                            myRecylerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
                            myRecylerView.setAdapter(chatBoxAdapter);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }


                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        socket.disconnect();
  }
}
```

Server

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send('<h1>Hello world</h1>');
});

io.on('connection',function(socket){
    console.log('one user connected '+socket.id);




    socket.on('message' , function (data) {
        console.log('======CHAT message========== ');
        console.log(data);
        socket.emit('message',data);

    });

    socket.on('disconnect',function(){
        console.log('one user disconnected '+socket.id);
    });

})

http.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log('server listening on port 3000');
})
```

Comment: i did solve the recyclerview error but the message socket is not emitted

Comment: thank you for you answer , please can you join your versions of the android and js parts so i can verify your answer thanks

Comment: @yassinebengharsallah I did so